# MySQL: Partition-like function for a single set of data?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table that has millions of records, and they utilize EFF_FROM and EFF_TO date fields to version the records.

99% of the time, when this table is queried by an application, it is only concerned with records that have an EFF_TO of 2099-12-31, or records that are active and not historical.

I copied just the active records to a test version of the table and the application's SELECT query went from 60 seconds to 3 seconds.

I don't necessarily want to partition every EFF_TO date. I don't want to add that overhead especially to processes that populate the table. I only want the optimization for querying records with 2099-12-31, and I want the performance to be instant.

Is there a straightforward way to do this? Or do I have to resort to creating an active table and a historical table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Partition like function for a single set of data?

This is something of any oxymoron, however you are asking about partitioning into two sets of data, one where EFF_TO is in the future and one where it is in the past.

> have an EFF_TO of 2099-12-31

Design fault - these should be null.

If they were null the the partitioning would be simple. As it stands you will have to drop and recreate the partitions - which is rather an expensive operation (have a look at tools for doing online schema updates).

You could minimize the impact by creating multiple partitions defining the period around NOW then adding an extra one onto the end of and removing one from the beginning at regular intervals.

> application's SELECT query went from 60 seconds to 3 seconds.

There are lots of other reasons why the performance improved than just the size of the table

- if it's doing a full table table scan, this is a design fault in the application.
- You're indexes may not be as up to date as they should be
- the logical structure of the indexes may be unbalanced and need optimized
- the physical structure of the table and indexes many be fragmented and need optimized

Comment: Okay I'll have to test some of these optimizations out and see what works.